# Delete specific dns record with dnspython when multiple are present

Tags: dns, dnspython

Consider following records in a dns server:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
test.example.com        3600  IN  TXT   "line1"
test.example.com        3600  IN  TXT   "line2"
```

Is it possible to delete 1 of the records and leave the other one?

When performing the delete with:

```
name = 'test.example.com.'
datatype = dns.rdatatype.from_text("TXT")
rdata = dns.rdata.from_text(dns.rdataclass.IN, dns_datatype, "line1")
update.present(name, rdata)
update.delete(name, rdata)
```

I get a NXRRSET (8) response.

When deleting with:

```
name = 'test.example.com.'
datatype = dns.rdatatype.from_text("TXT")
update.present(name, datatype)
update.delete(name, datatype)
```

then both TXT records are deleted (as expected).

My example is for TXT records but I have the same issue for other datatypes like A and PTR. Removing 1 of multiple records for the same name and type doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions? Or is this not possible?

**update**

When using the nsupdate cli tool it seems possible. When I send following commands, only 1 of the 2 entries are removed:

```
$ nsupdate -v -k example.com.key
server ns.example.com
nupdate delete test.example.com. TXT line1
send
```

Since it's working for dns update, I'll see to make an issue on the dnspython github page

Comment: You need to retrieve them all, then delete them all and set the ones you wish to keep.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek That's what I was afraid of :-) Doable ofcourse, but requires more coding. Would have been handy if it was forseen by dynamic dns updates.

Comment: We call them RRSets: records are a set, that is an **unordered** collection. Hence you can not pick one from it among the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing more with nsupdate the solution became clear. When using the present prereq, I just had to add them all so the preq was satisfied. The following code uses present and only deletesthe "line1" txt record:

```
name = 'test.example.com.'
datatype = dns.rdatatype.from_text("TXT")
rdata = dns.rdata.from_text(dns.rdataclass.IN, dns_datatype, "line1")
rdata2 = dns.rdata.from_text(dns.rdataclass.IN, dns_datatype, "line2")
update.present(name, rdata)
update.present(name, rdata2)
update.delete(name, rdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the present clause. Since 2 records are present and the update.present only conatins 1, it fails with the NXRRSET.
When omitting the prsent clause, the delete works:

```
name = 'test.example.com.'
datatype = dns.rdatatype.from_text("TXT")
rdata = dns.rdata.from_text(dns.rdataclass.IN, dns_datatype, "line1")
update.delete(name, rdata)
```